# Override MarkupExtension to take a second parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using MarkupExtension to display an embedded image resource. 
My problem is that, I want to change this image dynamically in my .cs class.
It means ProvideValue sould look like

```
public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider service, String ResourceID)
```

and then I can call it like

```
MakupExtensionClass.ProvideValue(service, "Project.Images.test.jpg")
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You cannot change the signature of the [ProvideValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.providevalue(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the `MarkupExtension` base class that WPF calls by overriding it so this is not possible I am afraid.